# Not able to merge two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am trying to merger two dataframes but getting error on the second one. i am trying to read two CSV's then convert them to dataframes then finally merge it. Below are the links for CSV files

1. Tradition for dataframe1
2. BGC for dataframe2

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n8ae91933ud4sdx/Tradition_Basis_RFR_2021_12_05_15_00_00.csv?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ryv5vkyj402xg2z/BGC_RUB_2021_12_05_15_00_00.csv?dl=0

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\atul.sanwal\\Desktop\\Tradition_Basis_RFR_2021_12_05_15_00_00.csv', header=0, skiprows=1, nrows=22)
data = data.drop(columns=["0"])
data['Mid_TRAD'] = data['Bid']/2 + data['Ask']/2
data = data.iloc[12:17, :].append(data.iloc[18:, :])
data = data.drop(columns=['Date', 'Time'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)


data1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\atul.sanwal\\Desktop\\BGC_RUB_2021_12_05_15_00_00.csv', header=0, skiprows=1, nrows=111)
data1 = data1.drop(columns=["0"])
data1['Mid_BGC'] = data1[2]/2 + data1[4]/2
data1 = data1.iloc[97:98, :].append(data1.iloc[105:, :])
data1 = data1.drop(data1.columns[1, 3, 5], axis=1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
print(df1)

result = pd.merge(data, data1)
print(result)
```

The objective of above script is to compare RUB data from two sources (Tradition vs BGC) for the below maturities
RUB 1yr
RUB 2yr
RUB 3yr
RUB 4yr
RUB 5yr
RUB 7yr
RUB 8yr
RUB 9yr
RUB 10yr

where the problem lies ? so when i run the script, the output gives the result from dataframe1

Note : BGC csv dont have headings

Expected Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFZyt.jpg)

Comment: _but getting error on the second one_ Are we supposed to guess what the error is?

Comment: return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'C'

Comment: the error will be more clear if you have both the CSVs open

Comment: @Fatemeh Sangin can you please help here

Comment: Hey, this is sorted